# Как добавить поле процент в rangeSlider?

Tags: jquery, rangeslider

Создаю новое поле в rangeSlider но из за не знания "как это сделать" столкнулся с проблемой 
Вот попытка :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maximshaxim.0fees.us/rangeslider.css">
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <span id="js-persent"></span>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="range" min="1" max="1000" step="2" value="10" id="js-ran" data-persent="10">
  <br>
  <br>
  <span id="js-input"></span>

  <script src="http://maximshaxim.0fees.us/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maximshaxim.0fees.us/rangeslider.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {

      var ran = $("#js-ran");
      var inp = $("#js-input");
      var per = $("#js-persent");

      ran.rangeslider({
        polyfill: false,
        onInit: function() {
          inp.text(ran.val());
        },
        onSlide: function(position, value) {
          inp.text(value);
          per.text(data);
        },
      });

    })
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Добавил поле data-persent так же показал плагину что он должен видеть что это должно выводится в span#js-persent таким образом :

```
        onSlide: function(position, value) {
        inp.text(value);
        per.text(data);
    },
```

но разумеется что не работает это так как нету основного вычесления которое должно выводить процент к примеру 0% 50% 100%

Как это можно реализовать ?

Рабочая ссылка без отображения поля с процентами: http://maximshaxim.0fees.us/

Comment: здесь не работают ссылки с моего домена , а в codepen не работают ссылки с cdn

Comment: `% = current/total*100`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  а весь код как будет ?

Comment: `per.text(value/(+ran.attr('max'))*100+"%");`

Comment: @StrangerintheQ напиши ответом - отмечу решением

Comment: что помогло да?)

Comment: @StrangerintheQ  да помогло - пиши ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все предельно просто, чтобы нормализовать значение, т.е. привести его в диапазон от 0 до 1
необходимо разделить текущее значение на разницу между максимом и минимум для этого слайдера.

```
let min = Number(ran.attr('min');
let max = Number(ran.attr('min');
let norm = value/(max - min);
```

Теперь чтобы привести его к % нужно его умножить на 100:

```
let percent = norm * 100 + "%";
```

Comment: @MaximLensky обратите внимание на минимум, в комменте его не было

Comment: работает даже так как в комментарии на ура ...посмотри ссылку http://maximshaxim.0fees.us/

Comment: @MaximLensky лучше поправить у меня вылезает лишняя десятая процента от того что минимум не 0 а 1, диапазон получается не 1000 а 1001 ну и все в таком духе

Comment: а да есть такая штука - куча 00000 или 99999 но это не критично ...